# linker script defined variables

Tags: c, extern, linker-scripts

I have been working on a program for a little while now, But recently I purchased a new laptop, after setting up my dev environment and pulling down a fresh copy of my repository I received the following two error.

```
ingw32/bin/ld.exe: target pei-x86-64 not found
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make: *** [makefile:43: Debug] Error 1
```

This I thought would be a simple error to correct, I generated a new linker script and changed the output format from `OUTPUT_FORMAT(pei-x86-64)` to `OUTPUT_FORMAT(pei-i386)`. I compiled it expecting a clean build, however I received the following error

```
./bin/Debug/cryptor.o:main.c:(.cryptor+0x41): undefined reference to `START_OF_PAYLOAD'
./bin/Debug/cryptor.o:main.c:(.cryptor+0x4d): undefined reference to `END_OF_PAYLOAD'
```

This is not an error I encountered on either my previous development box, or the linux box I have been adapting my project to work on

I have been using `mingw32-make.exe 4.2.1 x86_w64-mingw32` on my new system im using `mingw32-make.exe 4.2.1 i686-w64-mingw32`

The code paths are the same on both systems. this was a build off of a git clone

**main.c**

```
__attribute__((constructor(101), section(".cryptor"))) int construct()
{
        extern UINT64 START_OF_PAYLOAD;
        extern UINT64 END_OF_PAYLOAD;

.
.
.
}
```

**win32linker.ld**

```
 .cryptor BLOCK(__section_alignment__) :{
        *(.cryptor)
  }
  .payload BLOCK(__section_alignment__) : {
    START_OF_PAYLOAD = . ;
    *(.payload)


    . = ALIGN(0x200); /*minimum size of a section*/
    END_OF_PAYLOAD = . ;
  }
```

These two sections are defined immediately proceeding the `.text` section. I would appreciate any help in diagnosing the root cause of this problem. Documentation would also be appreciated.

Thank you in advance

### Edit

Here are the GCC flags I'm using

**Debug**

```
gcc -c  $(SrcPath)/main.c  -o $(Dpath)/cryptor.o
gcc -c  ./payload/$(Payload)/client/*.c  -o $(Dpath)/payload.o $(INC)
gcc -g -T $(SrcPath)/win32Linker.ld  $(Dpath)/cryptor.o $(Dpath)/payload.o -o $(Dpath)/cryptor.exe
```

**Release**

```
gcc -c  $(SrcPath)/main.c  -o $(Dpath)/cryptor.o
gcc -c  ./payload/$(Payload)/client/*.c  -o $(Dpath)/payload.o $(INC)
gcc -s -static -mwindows -fvisibility=hidden -T $(SrcPath)/win32Linker.ld  $(Rpath)/cryptor.o $(Rpath)/payload.o -o $(Rpath)/cryptor.exe -lCrypt32 -lWs2_32 -lBCrypt
```

Comment: You might be better off going back to a 64bit development environment, rather than trying to work around the additional changes that have happened as a result of swapping to a 32bit environment which looks to be what's happening here (can't be certain). The version of make isn't *that* important, but the versions of the other tools (such as gcc, ld, base mingw installation version) would allow better isolation of the problem

Comment: Thank you for the feed back, I'm trying to make certain that individuals can do the build off of my github so that I can build a community around my project ("which has been a truely painful experience in and of itself..."). but if it is more efficient to only apply a 64bit variant then I will have to redo my tooling as well as the documentation on my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a blurb on fixing this in an ld --verbose output. apparently, the root of the issue comes down to name mangling

The solution is simple because I only needed to address two possible Name mangling schemes in the linker script.

```
  .cryptor BLOCK(__section_alignment__) :{
        *(.cryptor)
  }

  .payload BLOCK(__section_alignment__) : {
        START_OF_PAYLOAD = . ;
        *(.payload)
        . = ALIGN(0x200); /*minimum size of a section*/
    END_OF_PAYLOAD = . ;
  }
  /*
   * took forever to figure this out. apparently, this is the correct way to make
   * sure the variables can be exported
   */
  _START_OF_PAYLOAD = START_OF_PAYLOAD;
  __START_OF_PAYLOAD = START_OF_PAYLOAD;
  _END_OF_PAYLOAD = END_OF_PAYLOAD;
  __END_OF_PAYLOAD = END_OF_PAYLOAD;
```

Now my imported symbols are reading correctly from the extern variable. The next step is to force the compatibility to be correct on both 32bit and 64bit architectures, and it should be in a cross-compile-compatible state.

---

### This ended up being a partial solution

In addition, I had to do some work on the header file and add the search_dir and output_format specifiers to get everything to work in a reasonable manner. This took some amount of time but this project is intricate and crafted to target multiple platforms. But since this is (due to the nature of the project) specific to the mechanics of my project I left those details out, but hopefully this answer will solve someone else's problem!

Comment: but it appears that different headers and other adaptations have to be made to make it cross compile the way I want it too